# How to use Tomcat with maven correctly in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, tomcat

I'm looking for the best way how to use Tomcat in Eclipse with Maven.

I have some experience developing Java EE applications and I'm expecting similar behavior when using Maven.

My requirements are simple:

- easy application building
- easy deployment
- if possible, hot swap

I do not know how Tomcat + Eclipse work in detail so I assumed that Maven command

```
mvn eclipse:eclipse -Dwtpversion=2.0
```

setups everything correctly, but I've got suspicion it's not working well (or at least as expected).

When project (let's call it test) is built in maven, result is in `${project}/target/test` folder. But it seems to me that classes for Tomcat are from different folder  (`${project}/target/classes` ?). This is IMHO wrong (correct me if I'm wrong), but maven can do other actions before building classes - code generation, resource filtering, AOP weaving and so on.

Are there some recommendations how to use it? Because performing `mvn clean install` from command line and deploying the result to Tomcat doesn't sound to me as IDE (Integrated development environment). It is possible to instruct maven eclipse plugin to setup it correctly?

I also tried to use `mvn tomcat:run` but here I'm completely lost, I'm getting errors I do not understand f.e.

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.cxf.common.classloader.ClassLoaderUtils.loadClass
```

and I have no idea why it's not working while using server runtime for tomcat 6 works fine from eclipse.

Is it possible to instruct Eclipse to perform let say `mvn install` when I save the class? Will it work than? Will that be quick enough (rebuilding only changed things + dependencies as I'm used to from standard JSE projects)?

Actually I'm using

- maven 3.0.4
- java 1.6
- eclipse 4.2.1 ([STS](http://www.springsource.org/sts) 3.2.0.M2)
- tomcat 6 (we are currently developing for Tomcat 6, but I guess it's the same for 7)

**edit**

some relevant parts from pom.xml

```xml
<project ...>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>...</groupId>
    <artifactId>...</artifactId>
    <version>...</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <properties>
        <spring.version>3.1.1.RELEASE</spring.version>
        <!-- WSDL -> Java (start) -->
        <cxf.version>2.7.3</cxf.version>
        <cxf-codegen-plugin.version>2.6.1</cxf-codegen-plugin.version>
        <cxf.sourceRoot>src/main/generated</cxf.sourceRoot>
        <!-- WSDL -> Java (end) -->

        <junit.version>4.11</junit.version>
        <maven.build.timestamp.format>yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm</maven.build.timestamp.format>
        <project.build.date>${maven.build.timestamp}</project.build.date>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        ...
    </dependencies>


    <build>

        <resources>
            <resource>
                <!-- filtering used to replace variables from in property files -->
                <filtering>true</filtering>
                <directory>${basedir}/src/main/java</directory>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>**/*.java</exclude>
                </excludes>
            </resource>

            <resource>
                <filtering>false</filtering>
                <directory>${basedir}/src/main/resources</directory>
            </resource>
        </resources>

        <plugins>
            <!-- add src/main/generated for maven -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.7</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>add-source</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <sources>
                                <source>src/main/generated</source>
                            </sources>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

            <!-- WSDL -> Java (start) -->
            <plugin>
                <!-- !!! READ !!! -->
                <!-- mvn cxf-codegen-plugin:wsdl2java NOT working, comment phase and run "mvn clean install -DskipTests") -->
                <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
                <artifactId>cxf-codegen-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${cxf-codegen-plugin.version}</version>
                <executions>
                    ...
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>

        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <version>2.5.1</version>
                    <inherited>true</inherited>
                    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                    <configuration>
                        <source>1.6</source>
                        <target>1.6</target>
                        <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>

                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <version>2.1.1</version>
                    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                    <configuration>
                        <warName>test</warName>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>

                <!-- resources in UTF-8 -->
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.5</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>

                <!-- JUnit -->
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.8</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <redirectTestOutputToFile>true</redirectTestOutputToFile>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>

                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
                    <configuration>
                        <wtpversion>1.5</wtpversion>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
    </build>
</project>
```

Comment: Could you please post your pom? Is the packaging set to war?

Comment: You need the servers view, right click and add server and select Tomcat, then you can deploy your web projects from within Eclipse.  That supports hot swap too.

Comment: @furtelwart: my actual pom.xml is to big to post it here (a lot of stuff is irrelevant for this question), but answer to your comment is, that I have `<packaging>war</packaging>` in my pom and also `<artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>` configured, my problem is not that it's not working, but it's only too complicated...

@Bob Flannigon: this is correct, but it takes wrong folder (${project}/target/classes) as I wrote in my question...

Comment: @Betlista Thanks for the info! Could you edit the relevant parts into the question? The properties for the `maven-war-plugin` could be relevant.

Comment: @furtelwart: pom.xml added ;-)

Answer (score 4):

I normally just use [m2eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org/m2e/) Maven plugin and import the project into eclipse.

Comment: I'm using m2e too, it's part of STS, but there no problem with import or building in Eclipse, but deploying and running in Tomcat...

Comment: You need the m2e WTP addon. Don't use eclipse:eclipse.

Comment: Here's a video tutorial on how to use m2e-WTP http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TksoKkSP208

Comment: Unfortunately there is same problem with m2e-wtp plugin, it uses resources before filtering :-(

Answer (score 2):

If you use `mvn eclipse:eclipse`, Maven creates the project settings specific for Eclipse. This way, no Maven command is executed by Eclipse for developing your application within Eclipse. Eclipse automatically deploys your application to the embedded Tomcat as always.

If you do a test build or production build, then you use Maven (e.g. `mvn package deploy`) This will create the war file and deploys it into a Nexus (or any other artifact repository, if configured). in your `target/` folder, you will then find a `artifactId-version.war` which you can deploy on any Tomcat you want.

Here's an article with some more hints: https://jacksonps4.me/wordpress/?p=1013